# Hierarchy is different in storyboard and when debugged while app is running

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have used `auto-layout` and `scrollview`. I have created hierarchy in storyboard which looks as shown below :

[image]

Basically `view` has `scrollview` inside it and `scrollview` has another subview `view1` inside it. Rest of the `views` are under `view1`.

While debugging one issue I am facing I show that `self.scrollView.subviews` prints 3 views. Out of them 2 are `ImageView`s. And those are not subview of `scrollview` as per the hierarchy in storyboard.

```
(lldb) po self.scrollView.subviews
<__NSArrayM 0xb66fe80>(
<UIView: 0xb74b110; frame = (0 0; 320 3240); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xb74b170>>,
<UIImageView: 0xb7e61c0; frame = (313 476; 7 3); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb7e62a0>>,
<UIImageView: 0xb7e6350; frame = (314.5 3091.5; 3.5 36); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb7e6430>>
)
```

What can be wrong here? Ask for any detail you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIView` on your console is this view

[image]

the 2 `UIImageView`'s are the scroll indicators

[image]

And one cool thing to debug view hierarchy is `recursiveDescription`.

```
po [self.view recursiveDescription]
```